# Proof of positive semi-definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices. Also, $A$ is positive definite. If all eigenvalues of $AB$ are non-negative, then $B$ is positive semi-definite.

In order to prove positive semi-definiteness, I need to show that $\lambda_B \geq 0$.

What I've done: $\prod \lambda_{AB} = \det AB = \det A \det B = \prod (\lambda_A) \prod (\lambda_B)$. We know that $\det A > 0$ and $\det AB \geq 0$. Thus, $\det B \geq 0$. There are 2 possible cases:

1. Exist at least 1 pairs of $\lambda<0$
2. All $\lambda \geq 0$. That's what I need.

The question is: how to prove that case #1 is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but a hint for an alternative proof: let $A^{1/2}$ be the (unique and positive definite) square root of $A$. Then $AB$ and $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ have identical eigenvalues (in general, $XY$ and $YX$ have identical eigenvalues for any two square matrices $X$ and $Y$). Now, for any vector $x$, show that $x^\ast Bx=y^\ast A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}y$ for some vector $y$.

Comment: "in general, XY and YX have identical eigenvalues". Interesting property. In what circumstances the rule doesn't hold?

Comment: I suppose the point is to prove that any $x = A^{1/2}y$ for some y. $A^{1/2}$ is nonsingular due to its $\det \neq 0$, thus $A^{1/2}y$ has solution for any x. And $x^* = (A^{1/2}y)^* = y^*(A^{1/2})^* = y^* A^{1/2}$. The last equality holds because $A^{1/2}$ is symmetric.

Comment: But I don't get how does this proof help?

Comment: @Max (1) $XY$ and $YX$ always have identical eigenvalues, otherwise we couldn't say "*in general*, $XY$ and $YX$ have identical eigenvalues". (2) Yes $x=A^{1/2}y$ is always solvable, but you also need to explain why $A$ has a positive definite square root. (3) By definition, a real symmetric matrix $B$ is said to be positie semidefinite if $x^TBx\ge0$ for every vector $x$.

Comment: 2) I don't know the proof, but I know that it's true. Having unique root is a property of any positive definite matrix. 3) I don't see that $y^* A^{1/2} B A^{1/2} y \geq 0$

Comment: @Max What are the eigenvalues of $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$?

Comment: (sorry for delay: my internet connection broke) I don't know. Using the same reasoning as in my post (via product determinants) doesn't preclude the existence of pair of negative eigenvalues of B.

Comment: wait, you wrote about the same eigenvalues for AB and $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$. Hence, the latter has no negative eigenvalues. Hence, B has no too.

Comment: Thank you user1551 for help :)